# Material ui 5 tab disappearing, when clicking, the tabs move to the left and the clicked tab disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tabs disappearing when clicking, most of the code is from material-ui docs.Here I am using material-ui 5. Don't understand why the code behaves like this. The styling is also from material ui 5. This is a simple navigation bar, with 5 tabs

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Tabs, Tab, useScrollTrigger, Box, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg';

const ElevationScroll = props => {
const { children } = props;

```
      const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0,
      });
    
      return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0,
      });
    };
    
    const ToolbarMargin = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
      ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
      marginBottom: '3em',
    }));
    
    const StyledTab = styled(Tab)(({ theme }) => ({
      ...theme.typography.tab,
      minWidth: 10,
      marginLeft: '25px',
      color: 'white',
    }));
    
    const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
      ...theme.typography.estimate,
      borderRadius: '50px',
      marginLeft: '50px',
      marginRight: '25px',
      height: '45px',
    }));
    
    const Header = props => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    
      const handleChange = (e, newvalue) => {
        setValue(newvalue);
      };
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ElevationScroll>
            <AppBar position='fixed'>
              <Toolbar disableGutters={true}>
                <Box component='img' sx={{ height: '7em' }} alt='company logo' src={logo} />
                <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} sx={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                  <StyledTab label='Home' />
                  <StyledTab label='Services' />
                  <StyledTab label='The Revolution' />
                  <StyledTab label='About Us' />
                  <StyledTab label='Contact Us' />
                </Tabs>
                <StyledButton variant='contained' color='secondary'>
                  Free Estimate
                </StyledButton>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </ElevationScroll>
          <ToolbarMargin />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

The tabs feels like disappearing, because the `selected` class on the tab is having the same color as the background color of the `tabs`. You can inspect the behavior in the `Inspect` tab of the browser developer tools.

You need to use different colors for the background and color of the active tab. Here I've changed the color of the `active` tab to demonstrate the difference by the `sx` prop of the `Tabs` component and use the class selector to target the `.Mui-selected` class of the active tab.

You can also use the `textColor` [prop](https://mui.com/api/tabs/) of the tabs to use the secondary color for the tab text.

```
<Tabs
  // textColor="secondary"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    marginLeft: "auto",
    "&& .Mui-selected": { // && are used to increase the specificity
       color: "#d1d1d1"
    }
  }}
>
```

I've created [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictabs-material-demo-forked-ekjlk?file=/demo.js) out of your example code.

Comment: thank you! It solved the issue. Have a great day. Thanks

Comment: Great. Thanks, you too!

Comment: I was facing a similar issue, and I was able to solve it by using this answer. thank you so much for taking the time to answer this question.